# Is there a name for this equivalence relation?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, terminology

Let $M$ be an arbitrary set and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of subsets of $M$. Is there a known name for the following equivalence relation or its corresponding partition?

$\sim_{M,\mathscr{F}}\,=\bigl\{(x,y)\in M\times M\bigm|\forall A\in\mathscr{F}\,(x\in A\leftrightarrow y\in A)\bigr\}$.

Comment: I would call it "the coarsest equivalence relation with which every set in $\mathcal{F}$ is compatible".

Comment: "The partition generated by $\mathcal{F}$"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathscr F$-indistinguishability.

In analogy with [Topological indistinguishability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability).

Answer (score 5):

The elements of this partition are precisely the atoms of the complete Boolean algebra generated by the family.

Comment: Which is atomic, so the equivalence classes are the atoms.